# Best way to insert error information from catch block in the table for stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, try-catch

I have stored procedure that process single row transaction. I would like to catch any errors and insert in `Error` table. Then use nightly process to forward the information from error table to developers. I'm wondering what is the best practice for this situation? Is there any good example on how to handle this? Here is my code and idea on what I have as of now:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertBuilding] 
    @Status BIT = 0,
    @Number CHAR(4) = NULL,
    @Name VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Contact VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Address1 VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Address2 VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @City VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @State CHAR(2) = NULL,
    @Zip CHAR(5) = NULL,
    @Phone CHAR(10) = NULL,
    @ActionID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET XACT_ABORT ON
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            INSERT INTO Buildings (
                Status, Number, Name,
                Contact, Address1, Address2,
                City, State, Zip, Phone,
                ActionDt, ActionID
            ) 
            OUTPUT INSERTED.RecID
            VALUES (
                @Status,@Number,@Name,
                @Contact,@Address1,@Address2,
                @City,@State,@Zip,@PhonePri,
                CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,@ActionID
            )
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            INSERT INTO dbo.ERROR(
                ErrorNumber, 
                ErrorSeverity, 
                ErrorState, 
                ErrorProcedure, 
                ErrorLine, 
                ErrorMessage, 
                ErrorDateTime
            )VALUES(
                ERROR_NUMBER(), 
                ERROR_SEVERITY(), 
                ERROR_STATE(), 
                ERROR_PROCEDURE(), 
                ERROR_LINE(), 
                ERROR_MESSAGE(), 
                CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
            )
        END CATCH
    END;
```

If anyone have any suggestions or example how this can be improved or good way to deliver these errors to developers please let know. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for.... looks fine to me! :)  You could try to play with `RAISEERROR` but honestly what you good looks like a good place to start.

Comment: @sniperd Are you saying that method in example above is good? Or that I should consider `RAISEERROR`?

Comment: I would probably do it the way you have done.  But just another way, if you wanted to log directly to the SQL log instead, would be to use `RAISEERROR` but I think I'd just do what you've already got.  The key is "What will be the easiest to report out of?".  I think the table you have made is perfect for that.  Using `RAISEERROR` might be 'proper' but then you have to parse a text file, yuck.  I like what you've done and I would go with it :)